# Android Studio 1.1 preview 2 single test run NullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, nullpointerexception

In Android Studio 1.1 preview 2, any single test auto-generated configuration (via context menu Run/Debug method test for example) produces the following NullPointer exception with stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jetbrains.android.run.testing.AndroidTestRunConfiguration.checkConfiguration(AndroidTestRunConfiguration.java:183)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.checkConfiguration(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:141)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.checkSettings(RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.java:358)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.canRunConfiguration(RunManagerImpl.java:524)
at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:97)
at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:73)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:398)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:61)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$4.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:375)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:319)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any recommendations on how to work around this?

Comment: If you'd like to "own" the answer, please feel free to add your own and then comment on the community post. I'll delete it. As you know, this post was receiving some backlash due to the format (question and answer in the question body). I edited to stop the bleeding, but you deserve the credit for your answer/workaround.

Answer (score 5):

> Workarounds for now:
>
> 1. Execute all tests in package or All unit tests
> 2. Open test configuration and re-select class and method explicitly from dialogs
>      after saving no issues with test run.
> 3. Install latest beta version from Android Studio Canary channel. Bug already fixed there and no new blockers found

<sub>This answer was originally posted [by the author](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28132189/1). This post has been edited to fit within Stack Overflow's Q/A format.</sub>

Comment: How do you even do a test?  I can't find instructions for android studio or the package structure.

Comment: @JustinThomas - New questions should be posted as questions, not as comments.

Comment: I assumed something so basic had a seminal post, so great that everyone using Android would know.  Rather than risk duplicate I thought I'd ask.